# Questions about cosmic sheets/walls/filaments

Tags: cosmology, gravity, space-expansion, structure-formation, galaxy-clusters

I had a couple of questions about cosmic filaments in the context of the cosmic web structure formation:

In this thesis ([https://www.imprs-hd.mpg.de/51939/thesis\_cpenzo.pdf](https://www.imprs-hd.mpg.de/51939/thesis%5C_cpenzo.pdf)), the author indicates in section 2.2.2 that as voids expand and merge with other bigger voids, the matter that they contain is forced into high density walls (sheets) around them, and they can evolve into high-density filaments.

This makes me wonder:

1. If, as cosmic voids expand, they expell matter onto their surroundings creating high-density walls and as matter density increases in them, doesn't the influence of gravity also increase, thus increasing the gravitational potential in these zones?
2. Could this affect orbits of systems that may lie near these walls (for example, by increasing the tidal influence on them as a result of the stronger gravity as matter accumulated in the walls/sheets)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Here, “expansion of cavities” does not mean their explosive expansion (as after supernova explosions), but simply a statement of the consequences of random gravitational compression of the cloud, which at first was more or less homogeneous. Particles of the cloud randomly gather into piles - they make up the “shells of cavities” - the surfaces of imaginary bubbles. In places where these shells randomly intersect, the concentration of particles is increased, so the mutual attraction is stronger there. Gradually, random piles form surfaces, threads (where the “surfaces” accidentally intersect), and finally, “points” (where the “threads” intersect). And at these “points,” of course, the gravitational potential is greatest.
2. This effect not only “can affect nearby systems”, it is in fact the main effect governing the emergence of all cosmological objects - from galaxy clusters to individual galaxies and star systems.